# What is the cardinality of the set of all infinite words formed using a finite alphabet of length > 1?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, infinity

I am trying to prove that this cardinality is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. I proved that if words are finite, then the set of all words is countable, however I cannot extend that proof to prove this question. Can anyone know how to prove?

Comment: How do you define an “infinite word?” Does it have a start? An end?

Comment: Do you know that $\wp(\Bbb N)$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it is also not clear in the question but I suppose it has a start like the first letter.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I did not understand what you said

Comment: @thisguy: $\wp(\Bbb N)$ is the set of subsets of $\Bbb N$; do you already know that its cardinality is equal to the cardinality of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Biject the set of words with the real numbers in $(0,1)$ written in base $n$, where $n$ is the number of letters in your alphabet.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott oh yes! I know that

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am not sure I get what you are saying

Comment: @thisguy: If your alphabet had 10 letters, let’s call them 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9, would it be obvious how to identify all of these infinite words in that alphabet with the real numbers between $0$ and $1$? Well, if you only had 5 letters, call them 0,1,2,3,4, could you identify them with the real numbers between $0$ and $1$ if instead of writing the latter in base 10 you wrote them in base 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct members of the alphabet. For each $S\subseteq\Bbb Z^+$ let $w_S$ be the word $c_1c_2c_3\ldots$ such that

$$c_n=\begin{cases}
a,&\text{if }n\in S\\
b,&\text{if }n\notin S\,,
\end{cases}$$

and verify that the map that takes $S$ to $w_S$ is an injection from the power set of $\Bbb Z^+$ to the set of infinite words over the given alphabet. This shows that the cardinality of that set of words is at least as big as the cardinality of $\Bbb R$.

To show that the cardinality of that set of words is no bigger than the cardinality of $\Bbb R$, let the alphabet be $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$, and for each $k$ let $d(a_k)=k$. If $w$ is the word $c_1c_2c_3\ldots$, let

$$x_w=0.d(c_1)d(c_2)d(c_3)\ldots\,,$$

viewed as a number written in the base $n+2$, so that

$$x_w=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{d(c_k)}{(n+2)^k}\,.$$

That is, if $n=6$, and $w$ starts $a_3,a_1,a_6$, then $x_w$ starts $0.316$ and is to be interpreted as a number in base $n+2$. Show that the map taking $w$ to $x_w$ is an injection from your set of infinite words to the unit interval $[0,1]$. Taking the base to be $n+2$ is what will let you show that the map is an injection ($1$-to-$1$).

Putting the two pieces together will then give you the desired result.